# How do I fix matchMedia 'doesn't seem to be working'

Tags: jquery, matchmedia

I'm coding a UI, and I want jQuery to check media screen `min-width`, then check if a div has class. If it does, it should toggle the class.

I have tried using code for `window.matchMedia()` but it doesn't work

```
if ((window.matchMedia('(min-width: 800px)').matches)) {
  if ($('.navbar-wrapper').hasClass('element-view')) {
    $('.navbar-wrapper').toggle('element-view');
  }
}
```

I expect the `.element-view` to be turned off or toggled if `.navbar-wrapper` has `.element-view` as class when media screen is of width 800px and above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, I realized I used `.toggle` instead of `.toggleClass` and I used this instead
`

```
$(window).resize(function () 
{
    if (($('.nav').width () >= 783) && ($('.navbar-wrapper').hasClass('element-view')))
    {
        $('.navbar-wrapper').toggleClass('element-view');
    }
});
```

`